# How do I extract data from tables in a CSV and manipulate that data in Ms word

Tags: python, csv, ms-word

So I have a CSV file that contains a huge amount of data with about 8 columns. I need help with how to extract this data and use this data to form different tables in MS word.

I have tried doing it manually but it takes too much time and I cannot complete it before the deadline

Comment: In the same page with different colums(like excel)? or First column data in first few pages, 2nd column data in next few pages and so on?

Comment: Do you have to use Python or can you use the (Windows) desktop version of Word? What kind of selections/processing do you have to do on the data? If it's just SQL queries, you *may* be able to do all that in Word just using one or more DATABASE fields.

Answer (score 0):

a) Use pandas to read the CSV file
b) Choose the part you want to export and save it in a different data frame
c) Save the data frame using name_of_your_df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
d) Embed the Excel sheet in MS Word using the following steps:
i)In Excel, select the chart, and then press Ctrl+C or go to Home > Copy.
ii)In your Word document, click or tap where you want the chart to appear, and press Ctrl+V or go to Home > Paste.